# Is it safe to use object destructuring to extract specific values from redux state using the useSelector() hook

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Would it be safe to extract specific values from the redux state using the `useReducer()` hook like below:

```
const {item1, item2, item3} = useSelector(state => state);
```

Or would that cause issues(with regards to rerenders and state), or be considered bad practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You should *never* return the entire `state` from a selector!**

Per the docs, [`useSelector` re-renders any time the selector return value changes after a dispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates).  Therefore, it's important that [**each call to `useSelector` should return the smallest possible piece of state this component needs**](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#using-multiple-selectors-in-a-component).

In this case, the best options are either three separate `useSelector` calls that each return one single field, or a single `useSelector` call that extracts just those fields and returns them.  However, because returning a new object reference will cause a re-render, you would either need to [use the `shallowEqual` comparison function](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react#selecting-data-in-list-items-by-id) or [a memoized selector function](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns#memoized-selectors) to avoid unnecessary re-renders when returning those fields together.